# What is the actual difference between using an inline-style and using a css-in-js library like styled components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles, css-in-js

**Writing an inline style in js,**

```
const styles = {
    background: 'blue',
    color: 'white'
}
```

and using it in the JSX as below

```
<div style={styles}> I am a div </div>
```

**Writing the styles using 'styled components',**

```
const Div= styled.div`
     background: 'blue',
     color: 'white'
`
```

and using it like,

```
<Div> I am a Div </Div>
```

Here what is the difference in using a css-in-js library and using the inline styles.

Comment: It is a wrong comparison, you need to compare CSS-in-JS vs Normal CSS

Comment: @DennisVash How could it be a wrong comparison when both the ways are doing the same thing. please explain. Is there any additional thing that a css-in-js library could do compared to writing them as inline (which i think is again a css in js way) :)

Comment: `<div styles={} />` - This will create inline styles (you can inspect the DOM to see). Using styled components, there won't be inline styles - instead those rules will get injected into a style tag, so in this sense it is 'normal' css

Comment: Inline styles only support a subset of CSS. Putting your styles inline into the DOM means you cannot use pseudo selectors, media queries, keyframes etc. Also some libraries (like jss, styled-components) even add support for neat, non-CSS-native features like nesting (just as SASS and LESS can do). Examples here: https://mxstbr.blog/2016/11/inline-styles-vs-css-in-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `styled.div` example is wrong, as in CSS-in-JS you write actual CSS and not an Object-like style:

```
// "Real CSS"
const Div= styled.div`
  background: blue;
  color: white;
`
```

Second, [CSS classes are generally bette](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)r, also, inline styles are considered bad practice as it is hard to re-use and maintain styles.

> CSS classes are generally better for performance than inline styles.

So in conclusion:

1. In inline styles, you write Object-like styles vs. actual CSS
2. Writing CSS allows all the benefits of CSS (like selectors).
3. Re-use and maintaining CSS is much easier than inline styles.
4. The real debate is between CSS-in-JS vs. CSS modules vs. SASS vs. Normal CSS (for that you can google or read related questions in SO).
5. Inline styles considered bad-practice as in addition they override all defined styles.
6. Inline-styles are limited in their functionality (try animating something in inline style or even implementing a media query).

Comment: I am aware of css classes (external styles), inline styles and styles tags (internal styles), just curious to know about writing a style directly in an object and using it with the style prop vs using a css-in-js library.

Comment: regarding your point 4) CSS modules/ SASS and normal CSS are related. they all help to do external css. May be i should have asked "what additional features does a css-in-js library provide compared to inline styles ( here we are concerned only about writing the styles in javaScript). Am i still wrong? @Dennis

Comment: But thanks for your answer, but hope you understood what i am trying to understand.

Comment: Your question should be: What are the limits of inline styles, it has nothing to do with CSS in JS

Comment: You are correct as well, but when thinking in React, when i say inline styles, i just mean writing some js object for styles, and when we say css-in-js, it is again writing some js for styles, which is different from an external css file (which is not js).

Comment: Although they both implemented with JS, their functionality is different and they treated differently in React. As CSS-in-JS generates classNames and inline-styles are just inline stylings of HTML elements.